# python: instaloader get comments about 40K 429 error

Tags: python, graphql, instaloader

I want to download comments of a post (about 40k comments)
but every time when I reach about 20k comments or 255 I get this error

```
unchanged -CThYNLunQR9\2021-09-07_13-09-25_UTC.mp4 exists 250…500…750…1000…1250…1500…1750…2000…2250…2500…2750…3000…3250…3500…3750…4000…4250…4500…4750…5000…5250…5500…5750…6000…6250…6500…6750…7000…7250…7500…7750…8000…8250…8500…8750…9000…9250…9500…9750…10000…10250…10500…10750…11000…11250…11500…11750…12000…12250…12500…12750…13000…13250…13500…13750…14000…14250…14500…14750…15000…15250…15500…15750…16000…16250…16500…16750…17000…17250…17500…17750…18000…18250…18500…18750…19000…19250…19500…19750…20000…20250…20500…JSON Query to graphql/query: 429 Too Many Requests [retrying; skip with ^C]
Number of requests within last 10/11/20/22/30/60 minutes grouped by type:
   d6f4427fbe92d846298cf93df0b937d3:    0    0    0    0    0    1
   2b0673e0dc4580674a88d426fe00ea90:    0    0    0    0    0    1
 * 97b41c52301f77ce508f55e66d17620e:  150  164  304  337  471  501
   51fdd02b67508306ad4484ff574a0b62:    6    7   20   24   27   29
Instagram responded with HTTP error "429 - Too Many Requests". Please
do not run multiple instances of Instaloader in parallel or within
short sequence. Also, do not use any Instagram App while Instaloader
is running.
The request will be retried in 6 seconds, at 12:20.
JSON Query to graphql/query: 429 Too Many Requests [retrying; skip with ^C]
Number of requests within last 10/11/20/22/30/60 minutes grouped by type:
   d6f4427fbe92d846298cf93df0b937d3:    0    0    0    0    0    1
   2b0673e0dc4580674a88d426fe00ea90:    0    0    0    0    0    1
 * 97b41c52301f77ce508f55e66d17620e:  150  162  303  336  470  502
   51fdd02b67508306ad4484ff574a0b62:    5    7   20   23   27   29
Instagram responded with HTTP error "429 - Too Many Requests". Please
do not run multiple instances of Instaloader in parallel or within
short sequence. Also, do not use any Instagram App while Instaloader
is running.
The request will be retried in 10 seconds, at 12:21.
-CThYNLunQR9: JSON Query to graphql/query: 429 Too Many Requests
Saved session to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Instaloader\session-rajofa1204.

Errors or warnings occurred:
-CThYNLunQR9: JSON Query to graphql/query: 429 Too Many Requests
```

I tried 4 times
what should I do to make it work
Are there any libraries to do what I want?
I opened up cmd and typed:

```
instaloader --login username --comments -- -shortlink
```

I didn't use multiple instaloader or I didn't use that account when the code was running

Comment: The error is explicit. You are being throttled, see account stats for details of what token and when. Try to narrow the query and issue batch request sparsely instead of brute forcing to get all comment in one shot. API prevents for riping, download 40k comments seems to be a pretty aggressive settings.

Comment: actually, I didn't get what you said :D
what should I do now?

Comment: I mean you are temporarily banned because you are asking to much comment in a single request see
 https://instaloader.github.io/troubleshooting.html#too-many-requests. To solve it, stop brute forcing, wait for ban is finished and refine your query see https://instaloader.github.io/cli-options.html

Comment: you mean i need to do something with these?
query_waittime(query_type, current_time, untracked_queries=False)
class RateController(context)
max-connection-attempts N

or i need to set for example 600 seconds in every 10k comments?
i mean 10K then 600-sec sleep then another 10K and so on?
I'm new to instaloader, im so sorry :)

Comment: if i bypass RateController would i get banned?

Comment: You cannot bypass the rate controller which is implemented at Instagram server side. You can adapt the rate controller at your client side to prevent being banned, by passing it will again let you brute force the API which seems to be your problem here, so don't. First things first. Read the doc which is clear and full of examples. Then as a first use case download a single post to check everything is working and you can actually retrieve data from the API. When you reach this point you should be able to deal with complexer queries without being banned.